# What are the three different kinds of Plugins available and their difference with observer in magento2?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, plugin

I want to know the different kinds of plugins, their utilities and difference along with their difference with observer in magento2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following link for better understanding.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

Comment: Yes I viewed this post but I want to know in details as to can it be created in the backed and plugin concepts.

Comment: https://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-plugin-and-preference/ refer this or you can read the magento devdocs

Comment: Ok thank you sir

Comment: @Hardik Makwana, Please don't put a single link answer. The answer should have some useful contain

Comment: Single link guides provide much better understandable solutions and the @Naiwrita09 is new one